How to compare groups, while accounting for daily fluctuations in all groups?
There is this new technology to obtain and store heat from surface water:
In summer, a machine pumps heated water from a lake against a heat exchanger. The heat is transferred to an underground water storage (which can be used in winter to heat up buildings, for example).
In some cases, a filter is placed before the heat exchanger to prevent aquatic organisms and debris to cross or clog the heat exchanger.
So there are 2 or 3 parts to this machine: a pump, a heat exchanger and (maybe) a filter.
There is data about the chemical parameters of the water before the machine and after each machine part. Such as: the concentration Chlorophyl a or the concentration dissolved oxygen.
Once every two weeks the chemical parameters were measured at at least two locations within/around the machine. There was 30 minutes between measuring one and then the other location.
Now, I want to find out whether any of the machine parts is affecting the chemical parameters. For example: does the concentration chlorophyl a get down by the filter, heat exchanger and/or pump? If so, by how much?
The trouble is that chemical parameters fluctuate A LOT in natural lakes. Chlorophyl concentrations can be high for some minutes and be low for the next. And at one day the concentrations might be generally higher than at another day. There isn't really a simple (linear) pattern to that.
I don't know if I can correct for the variation during the day.
To correct for the variation between days, I think I want to compare the measurement values for each machine part with each other for each measurement day separately. For example, at 11-11-2024 the concentration Chlorophyl a was significantly lower after the filter than in the lake, but on 9-8-2024 and 5-10-2024 it wasn't.
But then, how do I use all these p-values to get to one answer: does the filter lower the chlorophyll a concentration or not?

How do you get multiple p-values for these different days? If you have three measurements (the three dates you mention), one p value is already a lot, multiples is strange.

I thought: If I measured on one date the chemical parameters on two locations: 1) before the machine and 2) after the filter inside the machine. Then I would have two values for that day. I thought I could perhaps make a linear model through those two datapoints and then test whether the slope is significantly different from zero on that date? (I now doubt whether that is a good idea, since I have only two datapoints to make such a model).  If I make such model for every single day, I'll end up with a lot of p-values.

If you have only two points for a day, indeed, there is not an easy way to convert this to some significance. You would need more information on "normal" fluctuation, which is exactly what can follow from repeated measurements.

Ah, I see! Thank you for the clear explanation. Since there are no repeated measurements done on the same day, I might not be able to know what "normal" fluctuation looks like on that day. I wonder if it is of any use to create those linear models, collect the slopes of these models, and then do an one-sample t-test asking "what is the chance to get these slopes if they come from a distribution of slopes with mean slope = zero?"

The trouble is that a one sample t-test assumes that the slopes are normally distributed. I wouldn't expect these fluctuations to add precisely to zero, and I don't expect the standard deviation to be 1 persé.
